# solvePnP returns wrong result

Tags: c++, image-processing, opencv, computer-vision, pose-estimation

I'm using the function solvePnP to estimate the pose of my robot by visual markers. Some times I get wrong results in two consecutives frames. In the file problem.cpp you can see one of these results.

The points sets correspond to the same marker in two consecutives frames. The variation between them is very small, and the result of the solvePnP is very different, but only in the rotation vector. Translation vector is ok.

This happens approximely one time each 30 frames. I have tested CV_ITERATIVE and CV_P3P method with the same data, and they return the same result.

This is a example of the issue:

```
#include <opencv2/calib3d/calib3d.hpp>
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
using namespace cv;
int main(){
vector<Point2f> points1, points2;

//First point's set
points1.push_back(Point2f(384.3331f,  162.23618f));
points1.push_back(Point2f(385.27521f, 135.21503f));
points1.push_back(Point2f(409.36746f, 139.30315f));
points1.push_back(Point2f(407.43854f, 165.64435f));

//Second point's set
points2.push_back(Point2f(427.64938f, 158.77661f));
points2.push_back(Point2f(428.79471f, 131.60953f));
points2.push_back(Point2f(454.04532f, 134.97353f));
points2.push_back(Point2f(452.23096f, 162.13156f));

//Real object point's set
vector<Point3f> object;
object.push_back(Point3f(-88.0f,88.0f,0));
object.push_back(Point3f(-88.0f,-88.0f,0));
object.push_back(Point3f(88.0f,-88.0f,0));
object.push_back(Point3f(88.0f,88.0f,0));

//Camera matrix
Mat cam_matrix = Mat(3,3,CV_32FC1,Scalar::all(0));
cam_matrix.at<float>(0,0) = 519.0f;
cam_matrix.at<float>(0,2) = 320.0f;
cam_matrix.at<float>(1,1) = 522.0f;
cam_matrix.at<float>(1,2) = 240.0f;
cam_matrix.at<float>(2,2) = 1.0f;

//PnP
Mat rvec1i,rvec2i,tvec1i,tvec2i;
Mat rvec1p,rvec2p,tvec1p,tvec2p;
solvePnP(Mat(object),Mat(points1),cam_matrix,Mat(),rvec1i,tvec1i,false,CV_ITERATIVE);
solvePnP(Mat(object),Mat(points2),cam_matrix,Mat(),rvec2i,tvec2i,false,CV_ITERATIVE);
solvePnP(Mat(object),Mat(points1),cam_matrix,Mat(),rvec1p,tvec1p,false,CV_P3P);
solvePnP(Mat(object),Mat(points2),cam_matrix,Mat(),rvec2p,tvec2p,false,CV_P3P);

//Print result
cout<<"Iterative: "<<endl;
cout<<" rvec1 "<<endl<<" "<<rvec1i<<endl<<endl;
cout<<" rvec2 "<<endl<<" "<<rvec2i<<endl<<endl;
cout<<" tvec1 "<<endl<<" "<<tvec1i<<endl<<endl;
cout<<" tvec1 "<<endl<<" "<<tvec2i<<endl<<endl;

cout<<"P3P: "<<endl;
cout<<" rvec1 "<<endl<<" "<<rvec1p<<endl<<endl;
cout<<" rvec2 "<<endl<<" "<<rvec2p<<endl<<endl;
cout<<" tvec1 "<<endl<<" "<<tvec1p<<endl<<endl;
cout<<" tvec1 "<<endl<<" "<<tvec2p<<endl<<endl;

return 0;

}
```

And this is the result:

```
Iterative: 
rvec1 
[-0.04097605099283788; -0.3679435501353919; 0.07086072250132323]
rvec2 
[0.4135950235376482; 0.6834759799439329; 0.1049879790744613]
tvec1 
[502.4723979671957; -582.21069174737; 3399.430492848247]
tvec2 
[774.9623278021523; -594.8332356366083; 3338.42153723169]
P3P: 
rvec1 
[-0.08738607323881876; -0.363959462471951; 0.06617591006606272]
 rvec2 
[0.4239629869157338; 0.7210136877984544; 0.1133539043199323]
tvec1 
[497.3941378807597; -574.3015171812298; 3354.522829883918]
tvec1 
[760.2641421675842; -582.2718972605966; 3275.390313948845]
```

Thanks.

Comment: I am also facing the same issue, did you find an answer for it?

Answer (score 12):

I assume your input images are 640x480 and plot the two observed markers onto a white canvas. The marker from the first frame is red and the marker from the second frame is blue.

[image: Observed markers]

The square is roughly facing the camera in both images and is quite small on the screen. This means that it is very hard to estimate the position and rotation. Especially the distance to the object and the rotation around the x and y axis. A moderate change in the rotation around these axes will hardly be noticeable at all since the points would mostly move towards or away from the camera. Errors from the detection of the marker will have a big impact on the result.

The uncertainty in the estimated marker position and orientation can be estimated using the Jacobian obtained from the [projectPoints](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/calib3d/doc/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html?highlight=projectpoints#projectpoints) method.

```
// Compute covariance matrix of rotation and translation
Mat J;
vector<Point2f> p;
projectPoints(object, rvec1i, tvec1i, cam_matrix, Mat(), p, J);
Mat Sigma = Mat(J.t() * J, Rect(0,0,6,6)).inv();

// Compute standard deviation
Mat std_dev;
sqrt(Sigma.diag(), std_dev);
cout << "rvec1, tvec1 standard deviation:" << endl << std_dev << endl;
```

> rvec1, tvec1 standard deviation:
>   [0.0952506404906549; 0.09211686006979068; 0.02923763901152477; 18.61834775099151; 21.61443561870643; 124.9111908058696]

The standard deviation obtained here should be scaled with the uncertainty of the observed points (in pixels). You can see that the rotational uncertainty around x and y is bigger than around z and that the distance to the camera has a very big uncertainty.

If you copy the result to matlab you can plot the covariance matrix like this:

```
imagesc(sqrt(abs(Sigma)))
```

[image: Covariance visualization]

The image tells us that the uncertainty is biggest in translational z direction and that the estimate in this direction is quite strongly related to the estimates x and y position (in 3D space). Because the rotation and translation uses different units, it is harder to relate errors in rotation to errors in position.

If you want more stable estimates of the marker, I would suggest filtering the data with an [Extended Kalman Filter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Kalman_filter) or something similar. This would enable you to benefit from knowing that the images are part of a sequence and keep track of the uncertainty so that you are not being fooled observations with little information. OpenCV has some functionality for [Kalman filtering](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/video/doc/motion_analysis_and_object_tracking.html?highlight=kalman#kalmanfilter) that might come in handy.

Maybe you have solved your problems a long time ago but I hope this post can bring some insights to someone!

Comment: Great answer! I am also currently trying to estimate the covariances of poses I obtained through PNP estimation, and I was hoping you could shed some light on what you meant by "The standard deviation obtained here should be scaled with the uncertainty of the observed points"?

If my understanding is right, the Jacobian encodes how much the projections change based on small changes in R and t, and not really how bad the absolute reprojection error is. So if the camera is far away from the marker, it should result in a low std. dev even if the solution is wrong. How do we deal with that?

Comment: The Jacobian describes the relationship between the error in pose and the error in pixel coordinates. The precision of the corner detector will affect the precision of the estimated pose. Say that your corner detector has a standard deviation of 0.3 pixels, then you should scale the std_dev vector with 0.3 to get the standard deviation of the pose.

Comment: If the object is far away from the camera, the standard deviation of the pose will increase, not decrease. Note that the Jt * J matrix is inverted to get Sigma matrix.

Comment: Well, that's sort of the problem: in my test case, the standard deviation is decreasing with increase in distance (although the actual solution is getting worse). Would you by chance be able to take a look at this question I posted regarding this? 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48711052/opencv-projectpoints-inconsistent-covariance-standard-deviation-of-estimated